# Animation not running smooth (rotation)

Tags: java, android, animation, rotation, smoothing

I made a fairly simple animation in XML which I'm running on an image.
The animation makes the images rotate but the problem is that the animation is not very smooth.

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 28
```

XML animation **rotate.xml** code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<rotate android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:duration="600"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"/>
```

In my java/kotlin **MainActivity** class

```
lateinit var rotate: Animation
```

In my Oncreate function

```
rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate)
```

How I start the animation

```
btnFishing.startAnimation(rotate)
```

When I run the application on my phone and test the animation it looks very choppy and not smooth.
I tried recording the animation but it turns out that in the recording the animation is smooth hmm..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the question, the image I was trying to animate was to big. I first used 500*500px and I fixed it by resizing the image to 100*100px